# PayPal payment flow from one account to another account by click on button from my website

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I would like to a paypal transaction like below:

As per my requirement, when any buyer purchase any product from my website, so I want this amount move to first Admin PayPal account and when buyer click on **Purchase Complete Button**, the amount is automatically transfer to the merchant PayPal account without any PayPal authentication.

If somehow buyer will not click on **Purchase Complete Button**, it will automatically move after 15 days (For this we can use Delay Chain Payment).

But when any buyer click on **Purchase Complete Button**, so amount move from admin account to merchant account......is this process flow possible ??

Comment: How...?? Please tell me.

Comment: You write the script exactly how you described it. You can make payments through the PP api. So the rest is up to you.

Comment: I have a problem with "Purchase Complete Button" implementation..can you please tell..

Comment: @Er Sharad Soni: Describe your problem first. _I have a problem with "Purchase Complete Button" implementation_

Comment: Well you've not shared anything you've written so how you've even implemented this is a black box. I will refer you to the documentation : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/

Comment: @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd ....I have already explain my functional flow in above question. Is this possible to amount is automatically transfer to the merchant PayPal account without any PayPal authentication by a single click and clicking is done by buyer.

Comment: @Pogrindis ....actually right now I have some only flow but i am implementing any code regarding this flow, that's why i am not putting any code here...